# Handling headset button taps with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, media, exoplayer2.x, headset

I'm using ExoPlayer library to play video and all works fine, but I want additionally to handle taps on headset button. How can I make it?

All that I found [in docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons) is the following:

> If you are running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or later, call
>   FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS
>   MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback.onConnected. This will
>   automatically call your media controller's dispatchMediaButtonEvent(),
>   which translates the key code to a media session callback.

But it's a bit confusing, because about FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS
[docs say the following](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS):

> This constant is deprecated. This flag is no longer used. All media
>   sessions are expected to handle media button events now. For backward
>   compatibility, this flag will be always set.

Comment: Does it not just work by default with ExoPlayer's session module?